# How to use the limit.pendingCount variable in p-limit?

Tags: limit, es6-promise

I am using p-limit package to limit the # of concurrent requests made using Promise.all.

I would like to show the progress of the total requests, and see that there is a variable limit.pendingCount in the library.

My question is how can I use that variable to report progress, when I console log that variable, it only returns a final value of 0.

```
(async () => {
       const result = await Promise.all(promises);

       // eslint-disable-next-line
          console.log(limit.pendingCount);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are `await`-ing the `Promise.all` call, all promises will be completed by the time you reach your `console.log` statement.

Try checking the pending count without `await`-ing the promises initially. Any code after `await`-ing the promises will only be executed after all promises are completed (i.e. pending count is 0).

```
const numThreads = 2;
const numPromises = 4;

const pLimit = require("p-limit")
const limit = pLimit(numThreads);
const promises = new Array(numPromises).fill()
    .map((n, i) => i + 1)
    .map(n => limit(() => new Promise(r => {
            console.log(`Started Promise ${n}`);
            setTimeout(r, n * 1000);
        })
        .then(() => console.log(`Completed Promise ${n}`))));
trackProgress('After Promises Initiated', promises);
const result = await Promise.all(promises);
trackProgress('After Promises Awaited', promises);

/**
 * Prints the state of the current pending promises until all pending promises are completed. This works only for this sample; it is not production quality.
 */
function trackProgress(label, promises) {
    console.log(`[${label}] Tracking started.`);
    const printProgress = () => {
        if (limit.pendingCount > 0) {
            console.log(`[${label}] Pending: ${limit.pendingCount} of ${promises.length}`);
            setTimeout(printProgress, 1000);
        }
        else {
            console.log(`[${label}] Tracking completed.`);
        }
    };
    printProgress();    
}

/*
 * Output:
 * "Started Promise 1"
 * "Started Promise 2"
 * "[After Promises Initiated] Tracking started."
 * "[After Promises Initiated] Pending: 2 of 4"
 * "Completed Promise 1"
 * "Started Promise 3"
 * "[After Promises Initiated] Pending: 1 of 4"
 * "Completed Promise 2"
 * "Started Promise 4"
 * "[After Promises Initiated] Tracking completed."
 * "Completed Promise 3"
 * "Completed Promise 4"
 * "[After Promises Awaited] Tracking started."
 * "[After Promises Awaited] Tracking completed."
 */
```

---

Edit:

If you are looking to do a progress tracker, you may have better luck by adding callbacks to the end of the executed promises:

```
const numThreads = 2;
const numPromises = 4;

const pLimit = require("p-limit");
function executeRequests() {
    const limit = pLimit(numThreads);
    let numCompleted = 0;
    console.log(`${100 * numCompleted / numPromises}% Complete`);
    const updateNumCompleted = () => {
        numCompleted++;
        // TODO: Instead of console.log, update UI
        console.log(`${100 * numCompleted / numPromises}% Complete`);
        if (numCompleted >= numPromises) {
            // TODO: Instead of console.log, update UI
            console.log('All promises complete');
        }
    };
    const promises = new Array(numPromises).fill()
        .map((n, i) => i + 1)
        .map(n => limit(() => new Promise(r => {
                console.log(`Started Promise ${n}`);
                setTimeout(r, n * 1000);
            })
            .then(() => {
                console.log(`Completed Promise ${n}`);
                updateNumCompleted();
            })));
    Promise.all(promises);
}
executeRequests();

/*
 * Output:
 * "0% Complete"
 * "Started Promise 1"
 * "Started Promise 2"
 * "Completed Promise 1"
 * "25% Complete"
 * "Started Promise 3"
 * "Completed Promise 2"
 * "50% Complete"
 * "Started Promise 4"
 * "Completed Promise 3"
 * "75% Complete"
 * "Completed Promise 4"
 * "100% Complete"
 * "All promises complete"
 */
```

Comment: is there a way to get the pending count in between?  I want to show a progress bar that  goes from 0 to 100% based on the number of promises completed. I am going to try to use your technique to mark completed ones and see if I achieve my objective

Comment: @tanmay80 I updated to show a basic way in which progress could be tracked. This is not production quality, but does illustrate how the features can be used. If you are using this in production code then you will want to ensure that there can be no mismatch between the `pLimit` properties and the promises, such as by ensuring that the `pLimit` instance is confined to the listed promises only. Honestly, though, a better solution would probably be to wrap all promises with a callback on completion. Editing to add that now too...

Comment: How do you catch errors when running  inside the `limit()`?, I am getting `ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION` when it fails

Comment: @Álvaro have you tried adding a `.catch((resolve, reject) => { /* ... */ })` statement to the promise chain? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch

Comment: @MikeHill Yes but it did not work, I am using `Promise.allSettled()` instead and I can not get the catch on `status === 'rejected'` to capture the error. If it does not fail it runs really well.